# JavaScript method and property call difference confusion

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript code

```
var persona = {};
var _id = 3;

var getId = function () {
    console.log("getId called")
    return _id;
}
persona.getId = getId;
```

So when I am calling `getId` method using `persona.getId = getId;` it is not being called. And the console doesn't print

> getId called

---

UPDATE

---

After searching, understood the difference between them.
So updating my question with that.

> `persona.getId = getId;` & `persona.getId = getId();`

These two sentence do different jobs.

> `persona.getId = getId();`

The above statement stores the value returned by getId() function to persona.getId property.

> `persona.getId = getId;`

The above statement store the reference of the getId() function to persona.getId property. And since the value stored in `persona.getId` is function reference, so `persona.getId` is also a function. And it can be called using the below code-

`persona.getId();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I am calling getId method using `persona.getId = getId;` it is not being called

By using `persona.getId = getId;`, you're just creating a reference to the `getId()`. you're not calling the `getId` method.

To call the method you need to add `()` at the end function name.

```
persona.getId = getId();
//                   ^^
```

By calling the function `getId()`, the returned result will be assinged to the `persona.getId`.

**Demo**

```js
var persona = {};
var _id = 3;

var getId = function() {
  document.write("getId called")
  return _id;
};
persona.getId = getId();

console.log(persona);
```

Comment: What do you mean by creating a reference to the getId() ??

Comment: @Anita It means that you can call the function by it's alias. Try this in console `function a() { alert('In a'); } var b = a; b();`

Answer (score 0):

Of Course it wont call. For calling any method you need to add () at the end;

```
var persona = {};
var _id = 3;

var getId = function () {
    console.log("getId called")
    return _id;
}
persona.getId = getId;
```

here you are just creating reference of getId function.

To call getId you need to do this:

```
getId(); 
persona.getId();
```